# Modifying words before an acronym

Tags: acronyms

The `acronym` package automatically handles using the long version for the first instance and short version for subsequent instances.  However, for an acronym like near mid-air collision (NMAC), I find myself frequently saying `a \ac{nmac}` or `an \ac{nmac}` and that depends on whether the long or short form is being used. I.e., "a near mid-air collision" but "an NMAC".  I was wondering whether there is a way to annotate so that the a/an changes automatically depending on the form of `\ac{nmac}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us a little code to play around with. Just the minimum in order to have the first and second instance of `\ac{nmac}` compilable and visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `acronym` package allows it to define the indefinite articles for the short and the long form. Using `\iac`/`\Iac` instead of `\ac`/`\Ac` prefixes the acronyms with the thus defined indefinite articles (and uses `a` if no indefinite forms have been defined). Here is one possibility (the package has three different ways, search the manual for »indefinite«):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\acrodef{nmac}[NMAC]{near mid-air collision}
\acrodefindefinite{nmac}{an}{a}

\begin{document}

\iac{nmac} \par
\iac{nmac}

\end{document}
```

[image]